# Formatar data (de um arquivo txt) para Inserir no MySql

Tags: mysql, delphi, sql-insert

Segue o código:

```
    //informações necessarias para inserir no DB.
     coo := copy(lTemp,53,6);
                 ccf := copy(lTemp,47,6);
                 ecf := copy(lTemp,4,20);
     //Data sendo formatada para ser inserida
                 dtc1:= StrToDate(copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+copy(
                   lTemp,59,4));
    //Query para inserção de linha no DB.
    DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Close;
                 DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
                 DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tabc460(dtcompra, impcaixa, numcupom, ccf, valor) VALUES ( "'+DateTimeToStr(dtc1)+'", "'+ecf+'", "'+coo+'", "'+ccf+'", "'+FloatToStr(valortxt)+'")');
                 DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ExecSQL;
                 DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Close;
                 DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
                 DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM tabc460 ORDER BY dtcompra LIMIT 0,'+valor);
                 DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Open;
```

Bom, o que preciso é apenas acertar o formato da data, pois quando formata desta forma acima, ele aparece bem direitinho no Show Message, os dois formatos estao ok `dd/mm/yyyy`, mas quando eu vou ver no Banco de dados ele aparece todo embaralhado `20/03/2023` invés de `17/03/2014`.

O que poderia estar de errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para resolver este problema o ideal é utilizar parâmetros tipados pois protegem os dados de conversõe erradas, além de proteger seu código contra SQLInjection, portanto:

```
DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tabc460(dtcompra, impcaixa, numcupom, ccf, valor) VALUES (:dtcompra, :impcaixa, :numcupom, :ccf, :valor)');

DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('dtcompra').AsDateTime := dtc1;
DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('impcaixa').AsString:= ecf;
DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('numcupom').AsString := coo;
DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('ccf').AsString := ccf;
DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('valor').AsFloat:= valortxt;

DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ExecSQL;
```

Comment: esta retornando um erro de sintaxe. Como se a query não estivesse funcionando.

Comment: Qual erro de sintaxe? é em relação aos parametros? se for, dependendo do seu driver ou componente de acesso, adicione um caractere `p` antes de cada parametro tanto na SqlCommand quanto na hora de preencher os parametros

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código que escrevi baseado no código do @Caputo.

```
with DModuleGrid.ZQuery2 do
           begin
           //comparação de divergências (Identifica se sao mesmo diferentes e grava os valores no banco de dados)
             coo := copy(lTemp,53,6);
             ccf := copy(lTemp,47,6);
             ecf := copy(lTemp,4,20);

             dtc1:= StrToDateTime(copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+
             copy(lTemp,59,4));
             //FORMATANDO A DATA!!!!!!!! <<<------------------||||
             dtct := FormatDateTime('yyyy/mm/dd', dtc1);
             valortxt := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14)) / 100;

             DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Close;
             DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Clear;
             DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO tabc460(dtcompra, impcaixa, numcupom, ccf, valor) VALUES ( :dtcompra1, :impcaixa2, :numcupom3, :ccf4, :valor5)');
             DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('dtcompra1').AsDateTime := dtct;
             DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('impcaixa2').AsString:= ecf;
             DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('numcupom3').AsString := coo;
             DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('ccf4').AsString := ccf;
             DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ParamByName('valor5').AsFloat:= valortxt;
             DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.ExecSQL;
             //ShowMessage(DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.FieldByName('dtcompra').AsString);
           end;
```

Comment: @Caputo, desculpe-me, mas não deu pra postar mais cedo meu comentário, pois houve um probleminha com o site, mas enfim, meu amigo, deu certo aqui, o problema era a ultima linha aí do meu código `DModuleGrid.ZQuery2.Next;`, esava ocorrendo um erro de que não podia exectar esse tipo de query em um `Insert`, mas enfim. Obrigado pela ajuda. vou postar a resposta.